# Glossaries - hyperlink in acronym rather than page number

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, acronyms, hyperlink

By default the hyperlink in the list of acronyms is in the page number. Is there a way to change this such that by clicking on both the acronym and page number it takes you to its first occurrence? Kind of like using linktoc=all in for the table of contents.